# Angular 8: URL encoded form POST

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, post, urlencode

I want to post form data to a server that accepts and returns text/html/xml. I am effectively trying to emulate a normal URL encoded form POST. My Angular 8 POST function successfully posts (200 OK), but the server can't understand the data because it is JSON and not URL encoded.

Response and request headers state `Content-Type: text/html; Charset=utf-8` and `Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*` and I have added `responseType: "text"` to the httpClient options. Why is the server still being sent JSON and not URL encoded data?

```js
// obj2 = output from ngForm
// baseUrl2 = server that sends and receives text/html/xml

public postForm(obj2) {
    return this.httpClient
    .post(this.baseUrl2, obj2, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            Accept: "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*"
        }),
        responseType: "text"
    })
    .map(data => data);
}
```

Form data sent:

```js
{"Form data":{"{\"personsNameText\":\"name9\",\"centreEmailAddressText\":\"name9@name.com\",\"centreTelephoneNumberText\":123456789,\"centreNumberText\":\"ab123\",\"centreNameText\":\"ab123\",\"invoiceText\":\"123456789\",\"currencyText\":\"GBP\",\"amountText\":\"100\",\"cardtypeText\":\"Credit card\",\"commentsText\":\"Comments.\",\"declarationText\":true}":""}}
```

What I want:

```js
personsNameText=name9?centreEmailAddressText=name9@name.com?centreTelephoneNumberText=123456789?centreNumberText=ab123?centreNameText=ab123?invoiceText=123456789?currencyText=GBP?amountText=100?cardtypeText=Credit card?commentsText=Comments.?declarationText=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the type of the `obj2` object here but I'll assume it's somethings like

```
interface UserFormData {
  ['Form data']: { [name: string]: value };
}
```

You would need to transform this to `FormData` before posting it. Something along the lines:

```
const formEncodedObj2 = new FormData();
const obj2Keys = obj2['Form data'];
Object.keys(obj2Keys).forEach(key => formEncodedObj2.append(key, obj2Keys[key]));
```

And then send the `formEncodedObj2` object.

Comment: Thanks, Vlad. `obj2` contains: `{
  "personsNameText": "name9",
  "centreEmailAddressText": "name9@name.com",
  "centreTelephoneNumberText": 123456789,
  "centreNumberText": "ab123",
  "centreNameText": "ab123",
  "invoiceText": "123456789",
  "currencyText": "GBP",
  "amountText": "100",
  "cardtypeText": "Credit card",
  "commentsText": "Comments.",
  "declarationText": true
}`

Comment: this is what is posted after Vlad's solution: `{"Form data":{"100":"","123456789":["",""],"-----------------------------18467633426500":["","","","","","","","","","",""],"Content-Disposition: form-data; name":["\"personsNameText\"","\"centreEmailAddressText\"","\"centreTelephoneNumberText\"","\"centreNumberText\"","\"centreNameText\"","\"invoiceText\"","\"currencyText\"","\"amountText\"","\"cardtypeText\"","\"commentsText\"","\"declarationText\""],"name9":"","name9@name.com":"","ab123":["",""],"GBP":"","Credit card":"","C":"","true":"","-----------------------------18467633426500--":""}}`

Comment: Make sure you know your data type since there is a higher order key in there called "Form data" that seems like it messes stuff up. Main idea is: make a `FormData` object and `append` to it the key-value pairs you wish to send.

Comment: Yes. What I don't understand is where the extra data, such as "Form data" came from, since the source was the contents of `obj2` which is just name:value pairs. Yes, I've been using .append() too. I'll post any breakthroughs I have. Thanks, Vlad.

Answer (score 0):

So, this solution solved various problems for me:

1. Posting x-www-form-urlencoded data using Angular 8's forms and HttpClient
2. Correcting unwanted encoded characters

   - My specific problem was that a unique verification string contained ampersands that were being converted to HTML entities, i.e. `&` to `&amp;`.

```js
// userdata.service.ts

public postForm(obj) {
  return this.httpClient
    .post(this.baseUrl2, obj, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Referer": "http://referer.com" // Replace with your own.
      }),
      responseType: "text"
    })
    .map(data => data)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}

// app.component.ts

PostForm(userdata) {
    // Stringify and convert HTML entity ampersands back to normal ampersands.
    const corrected = JSON.stringify(userdata).replace(/(&amp;)/gm, '&');
    // Convert back to JSON object.
    const corrected2 = JSON.parse(corrected);
    // entries() iterates form key:value pairs, URLSearchParams() is for query strings
    const URLparams = new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(corrected2));
    // Convert to string to post.
    const final = URLparams.toString();
    // Post it
    this.userdataService.postForm(final).subscribe(reponse2 => {
        console.log(reponse2);
    });
}
```

[URLSearchParams()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) was the breakthrough and, as Vlad suggested, being absolutely sure of the type one is dealing with. I should have used [Types](https://angular.io/api/core/Type) to avoid confusion. I probably should use [Angular Interceptors](https://blog.angularindepth.com/top-10-ways-to-use-interceptors-in-angular-db450f8a62d6) to deal with the character manipulation.